# Substitute remote webworkers with local string

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Instead of calling a remote script to be executed in a web worker like `new Worker('script_on_server.js');` can I just somehow pass in a string to a worker to be interpreted as a script? Something like:

```
var calculate = new Worker('function (args) {...}').apply(args);
```

If this can't be accomplished by using web workers maybe there's another threading solution for javascript.

Comment: The answer is no... according to spec, Worker constructor must be instantiated with script URL. http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#dedicated-workers-and-the-worker-interface

Comment: and no alternatives?

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think so. `SharedWorker` also requires script url. If you ever find an alternative, it wouldn't be Workers.